# safari push notification - push package issue

Tags: safari, push-notification, safari-push-notifications

when I try to download my push package it returns the push package with all the contents such as iconsets, mainfest.json, website.json, signature but while connecting it returns "Missing file in push package". Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

What is the file structure of your downloaded zip look like? It should only contain one directory. It should look like:

```
ZIP/
    directory
        icon.iconset (directory)
        maifest.json
        signature
        website.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and could not figure it out.  I ended up using the [push_package](https://github.com/SymmetricInfinity/push_package) gem

Answer (score -1):

**Follow this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html) and [github repo](https://github.com/nishantmendiratta/Safari-Push-Notifications-Heroku), they include sufficient information required to create a safari push notifications.**